# Can't use token from Okta to authenticate with StrapiJS

Tags: vue.js, openid, access-token, okta, strapi

I have a Vuejs2 app with Strapi 3.0 for the backend and I need to use Okta for user management. A simple login form from my Vuejs app to authenticate with Strapi/auth/local works.

I have an Okta tile setup has a SPA using OpenId Connect which returns the user profile and email. I followed the Okta Vuejs example to setup the login process between Vuejs app and Okta, which works. My problem is authenticating with Strapi using the token returned by Okta.

I added Okta as a provider in 
/plugins/users-permissions/services/Provider.js
and 
/plugins/users-permissions/config/functions/bootstrap.js

The Okta token is properly stored in the localStorage
[localStorageOKta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpXdR.png)

Here a screenshot of the object I try to used to connect with Strapi
[OktaObjectInConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfYeF.png)

And here's a screenshot of my Vuex store action attempting to connect to Strapi
[VuexActionAuthWithStrapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1q1v.png)

Here the error I get Strapi logs... not very helpful.
[Symbol(Symbol.iterator) of Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqvay.png)

What am I missing here? Is the request from Vuejs to Strapi too complex? Is it missing a parameter? I have been on this for more than 2 weeks and I'm starting to lose it. Thanks in advance.

I added my Okta tile setup just in case.
[OktaTileSetup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVyM5.png)